# Gravity Forms Personality Quiz Add-On

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I'm trying to figure out how to hack this plugin Gravity Forms Personality Quiz Add-on. (https://wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-personality-quiz-add-on/)

Basically I've created 4 fields in ACF to add more "weight" to specific questions within the quiz, to essentially 'force' a tiebreaker rather then use the random option tie breaking function the plugin comes with. Within the backend ACF fields we store the numbers of the questions in order of importance (ie. field one has the number 2 in it to denote that question 2 is the most important question in the event of a tiebreaker).

Each answer has a specific letter value associated with it N,I,S or D. In the event of a tie (ie. same number of "N's" & "I's" chosen) the code should cycle through and see if first tiebreaker question (question 2 in this case) has a value of either N or I. If so, then that letter would be the final result. If neither N or I was chosen for question 2 the tiebreaker code should then move on to the next highest weighted question and preform the same test, and so on.

Problem is that it only seems to work for the first quiz and ONLY "Your Love Style Quiz" the partner quiz doesn't work at all.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to get this working please let me know.

Here is the link to the thread and my code: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/tie-breakers-via-acf/

Answer (score 0):

Got this working, seems that having questions prior to the quiz questions were interfering with the quiz results. By moving them to the bottom, the tiebreakers now work as expected.